# Facebook icon not visible in envelope menu

Tags: facebook, system-tray

On a clean 13.04 install, I have registered facebook in the online accounts, authorized facebook to allow ubuntu access, and installed the app.

But still I am not getting the facebook shortcut icon in the envelope menu (that I used to get in 12.10) at the top right. Please help.

Slightly off topic, but for pidgin, now I am getting an icon integrated in the envelope drop-down, instead of a seperate icon on the systray i had got in 12.10.

Now its not shown, even if I have facebook actually open in browser....any help?

Comment: I did another clean install of 13.04 and this is definitely an issue. Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: does facebook.com show in the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains` and `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications` ?

Comment: I get `['facebook.com', 'mail.google.com']` for the first command and `['empathy.desktop', 'GMailmailgooglecom.desktop']` for the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard about twitter and facebook integration in Ubuntu Raring using the Friends App (Gwibber re-written) and installed it as a desktop client.

> sudo apt-get install friends-app

...and viola! the facebook icon appeared in the envelope menu!

Answer (score 1):

Appearance of facebook in the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains` indicates that you have accepted and installed the integration plugin.

`gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications` shows the list of applications that actually have an entry in the messaging menu. Facebook appears missing in your case.

*Solution:*
Check if the file `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/facebookfacebookcom.desktop` exists. (replace $USER with your username.)

If it doesn't, remove facebook from `com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains` (Use dconf editor. `com>canonical>unity>webapps`). This will cause firefox to prompt again, accept, and the desktop file should appear.

Open dconf-editor and add the filename `facebookfacebook.com.desktop` to `com.canonical.indicator.messages applications`. The facebook indicator should now appear in the messaging menu.

Comment: @Mahesh....okay..so the file was there, but there was no entry in `com.canonical.indicator.messages applications`. So I added the filename, and tried, restarted and tried etc etc...nothing worked... Then I removed the entry from unity > webapps, and re-accepted the prompt on site visit....this time the entry was created at both locations in dconf editor...but still no facebook icon.

Comment: I removed the desktop file, removed it from both locations in dconf editor, and re-accepted the site popup....everything was regenerated all, right...but still no facebook icon

Comment: @charlie Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-webapps-facebookmessenger`

Comment: Tried that too, still nothing :(

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry..

Comment: No need to be sorry @Mahesh... thanks a lot for your attempts. Maybe you have better luck in some of my other issues.

Comment: I solved the issue, please see the answer below. Just thought you would like to know.